# foreignKeyConstraintExists Precondition Seems Not Adequate If Foreign Keys with Same Reference Details but Different Names Exist

Tags: liquibase

When I upgrade an existing database using a Liquibase script (*the database has never been upgraded by Liquibase*), the following error occurs.

```
liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set ../master.xml::5::ray.chen:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-02275: such a referential constraint already exists in the table
 [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE CRDM_RCHEN.SOME_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT SOME_TABLE_FK FOREIGN KEY (COLUMN_2) REFERENCES CRDM_RCHEN.SOME_OTHER_TABLE (COLUMN_1)]

        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:605)
        at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:51)
        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:79)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:214)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1126)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:184)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

I double checked the Liquibase script and the database, a foreign key named **SOME_TABLE_1_FK** already exists in the database. The root cause should be that the Liquibase script is going to add a foreign key named **SOME_TABLE_FK** but a foreign key named **SOME_TABLE_1_FK** already exists with same reference details and different name. It seems the database does not allow 2 foreign keys which names are different but reference details are same.

Do you have any solutions or ideas about this issue? Thanks.

Here is the related Liquibase script. I use the **foreignKeyConstraintExists** precondition to check whether the foreign key **SOME_TABLE_FK** exists, if not, add it; but if there is a foreign key existing with same reference details but different name (*the above case*), the changeset will be executed and the above error occurs.

```
<changeSet author="ray.chen" id="5">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <foreignKeyConstraintExists foreignKeyName="SOME_TABLE_FK" />
        </not>
    </preConditions>
    <addForeignKeyConstraint constraintName="SOME_TABLE_FK" baseTableName="SOME_TABLE" baseColumnNames="COLUMN_2" referencedTableName="SOME_OTHER_TABLE" referencedColumnNames="COLUMN_1" deferrable="false" initiallyDeferred="false" onDelete="RESTRICT" onUpdate="RESTRICT" />
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `foreignKeyConstraintExists` provided by liquibase requires `foreignKeyName` to be passed. in order to check if there is a foreign key without name then you need to write custom precondition. an example for the same can be seen below:

```
<preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
    <not>
        <customPrecondition className="com.ctp.liquibase.ForeignKeyExistsPrecondition">
            <param name="schemaName" value="MYSCHEMA"/>
            <param name="tableName" value="TABLE"/>
            <param name="columnName" value="COLUMN"/>
            <param name="foreignTableName" value="FTABLE"/>
        </customPrecondition>
    </not>
</preConditions>
```

The above will check if a column on a table has a foreign key constraint for a foreign table.

more you can find [here](http://blog.ch.atosconsulting.com/database-migrations-with-liquibase/).

Comment: Thanks Deendayal Garg. I didn't know how to write a custom precondition until I viewed your answer and provided article. Thanks.

Comment: The linked article isn't available anymore, so take a look at the archive.org WayBackMachine: https://web.archive.org/web/20160930150639/blog.ch.atosconsulting.com/database-migrations-with-liquibase/

Examples in the liquibase source code
- https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/66e46b7372b85b5a3729c668bdf333989f030238/liquibase-standard/src/test/java/liquibase/precondition/ExampleCustomPrecondition.java#L7
- https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/66e46b7372b85b5a3729c668bdf333989f030238/liquibase-standard/src/test/resources/liquibase/parser/core/yaml/testCasesChangeLog.yaml#L376

Answer (score 1):

Why not just check for both/all names?

```
<preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
    <not>
        <foreignKeyConstraintExists foreignKeyTableName="SOME_TABLE" foreignKeyName="SOME_TABLE_FK"/>
    </not>
    <not>
        <foreignKeyConstraintExists foreignKeyTableName="SOME_TABLE" foreignKeyName="SOME_TABLE_1_FK"/>
    </not>
</preConditions>
```